# DLL compiled with QT and used with C# WCF application, not able to download files > 20K

Tags: c#, c++, qt, wcf, shared-libraries

I am using a C++ dll compiled with QT, which is being used by a C# WCF application. The dll in turn is communication with a remote API. Every thing was working good till I wanted to download files from that API to QT/C++ dll and back to WCF service.

Note that files are getting downloaded with `QNetworkAccessManager`. But when its larger than approx 18 KB. I am getting empty response. But the same code works fine for all files while tested in a Console Application.

Also note that I am not able to live debug it due to some limitations.

Does the un-managed code behave differently while running with a managed parent application? Or what could be the reason and how to fix this?

Comment: "I am not able to live debug it due to some limitations." That's a major issue. You'll likely go nowhere without being able to debug your C++ code **and** Qt code. Please build your own copy of Qt, and set everything up so that the VS debugger will work on your code.

Comment: @KubaOber Couldn't live debug, though I am checking the log from produced dll. It just  skips the step where I try to check reply length. Other wise it works further and isn't crashing or something like that. OR otherwise how to live debug the app in QT which is a DLL project, tried to run it with WCF app as parent application but it isn't running with it.